Issue with Redirecting to Authentication Page in ASP.NET MVC Application
I'm encountering an issue with redirecting to authentication page in my ASP.NET MVC application. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I have configured my application to use AAD for authentication.
I've set up the redirect URIs in the Azure portal to match the ones used in my application (https://localhost:44341/signin-oidc, https://localhost:44387/signin-oidc, https://localhost:44320/signin-oidc).
I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Security and Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect for authentication middleware.

However, when I run the application and try to access the authentication-protected routes, I'm not being redirected to the AAD authentication page as expected. Instead, I remain on the same page without any redirection or error message.
Here are the relevant snippets of my code:
Startup.Auth.cs:
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                        context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = string.Empty;
        }

        if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return value + "/";
        }

        return value;
    }
}

Startup.cs:
namespace OidcTestDemo
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}

Web.config:
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44341/signin-oidc" />
</appSettings>

Also, AccountControlller is not being called:
namespace OidcTestDemo.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
               new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
               OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}


Check the .cshtml files in your project.

yes, _LoginPartial.cshtml file was missing.

I was able to redirect to the Authentication page in the ASP.NET MVC application.
Below is my _LoginPartial.cshtml code.
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="navbar-text">
            Hello, @User.Identity.Name!
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign out", "SignOut", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
        </li>
    </ul>
    </text>
}
else
{
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class ="nav-link" })</li>
    </ul>
}

SignOutCallback.cshtml :
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sign Out";
}
<main aria-labelledby="title">
    <h2 id="title">@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <p class="text-success">You have successfully signed out.</p>
</main>

Add the below line to the _Layout.cshtml.
_Layout.cshtml :
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")


Output :
It ran successfully, and I was able to log in as follows.






Correct, I forgot to add LoginPartial view. Thanks for the solution!

After following the same steps as mentioned above, upon entering the OTP, I encountered the error: "Server Error in '/' Application. IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'."
